# How do we use 2 column's difference value for TOP query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-join

I want to generate N number of rows from Table A.
where N is difference of column2- column1 from Table A for all the records in the table.

I don't want to use loops for this.

Sample Query

```
Select TOP (tbl1.Column2 - tbl1.Column1) tbl1.Column3, tbl2.Column1 
from TableA tbl1 cross join
     TableB tbl2
where tbl1.ID= 10
```

but this gives me below error

> The reference to column "Column2" is not allowed in an argument to a TOP, OFFSET, or FETCH clause. Only references to columns at an outer
>   scope or standalone expressions and subqueries are allowed here.

What is the alternate to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you would use `TOP` with `ORDER BY`.

In any case, you can do what you want using window functions:

```
select column3, column1
from (select (tbl1.Column2 - tbl1.Column1) as numrows,
             tbl1.Column3, tbl2.Column1,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum 
      from TableA tbl1 cross join
           TableB tbl2
      where tbl1.ID = 10
     ) t
where seqnum <= numrows;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the difference into a subquery then selecting the top from that:

```
Select TOP DiffColumn, Column3, Column1
From (Select (tbl1.Column2 - tbl1.Column1) as DiffColumn, tbl1.Column3, tbl2.Column1 
from TableA tbl1 cross join
 TableB tbl2
where tbl1.ID= 10)
```

Also, you were missing a comma before tbl1.Column3 in your original query.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to generate N number of rows from Table A. where N is
>   difference of column2- column1 from

Saying that N=diff. of col1 and col2 is wrong.Becasue it again return many rows.
you hv to b very specific. like max(col2)-max(col1).i.e explain how to calculate diff of col1 and col1.

```
Declare @diff int=10
declare @t table(col1 int)
insert into @t VALUES(1)
select * from @t A
cross apply(select distinct number from master..spt_values where  number>0 and  number<=@diff)ca

or

select top (@diff)* from @t A
```